# Battery information in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, settings, battery

In Freya there was a pretty good battery manager, is it possible to use the same program in Loki? 
UPD: the question is about this program (screenshot from home PC with UPS):
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by battery manager? The wingpanel indicator or something else?

Comment: In Freya, if you click the wingpanel indicator, you can open smth like battery statistics page with lots of useful data.

Comment: Side issue: is it possible to show both percentage and remaining battery life on wingpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was (and is) a Gnome application that you can run with the `gnome-power-statistics` command (if neeeded, it is in the `gnome-power-manager` package).

[image]